# How to test REST API using Chrome's extension "Advanced Rest Client"

Tags: rest, google-chrome-extension

Following the instructions at the link below, I successfully built a REST API for my Django application: http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart.

I can test it by doing the following from the Unix prompt:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u root:myPassword http://www.myWebsite.com/users/
```

It works :)

However, I would like to use the Chrome extension Advanced Rest Client to test this same functionality.
I have installed the extension, but I don't know where/how to put the fields. When I make my educated-guess (as you can see in the screenshot), it rejects it saying "Authentication credentials were not provided"

[image: screenshot of failing request]

How/where should I specify my parameters to the REST API?

Answer (score 99):

The discoverability is dismal, but it's quite clever how Advanced Rest Client handles basic authentication. The shortcut abraham mentioned didn't work for me, but a little poking around revealed how it does it.

The first thing you need to do is add the `Authorization` header:
[image: menus]

Then, a nifty little thing pops up when you focus the `value` input (note the "construct" box in the lower right):
[image: construct the auth value]

Clicking it will bring up a box. It even does OAuth, if you want!
[image: convenient inputs]

Tada! If you leave the value field blank when you click "construct," it will add the `Basic` part to it (I assume it will also add the necessary OAuth stuff, too, but I didn't try that, as my current needs were for basic authentication), so you don't need to do anything.
[image: fills in the field as needed]

Comment: For basic authentication - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SP1hgm9JqA . In "Headers form" tab, add a header "Authorization". It will do auto-suggest once you start to type. In the value, click Edit (pencil) button and type auth credentials in the pop-up.

Answer (score 10):

From the screenshot I can see that you want to pass "user" and "password" values to the service. You have send the parameter values in the request header part which is wrong.
The values are sent in the request body and not in the request header.
Also your syntax is wrong.
Correct syntax is: `{"user":"user_val","password":"password_val"}.`
Also check what is the the content type. It should match with the content type you have set to your service.

Answer (score 7):

This seems a very old question, but I am providing an answer, so that it might help others.
You can specify the variables in the second screen in the form section, as shown below or in the
RAW format by appending the variables as shown in the second image.

[image: Specify Form Variables]

[image: Specify in RAW format]

If your variable and variable values are valid, you should see a successful response in the response section.

Comment: what if it's a GET request?

Comment: I had to set the Content-Type header explicitly, with the value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 6):

The shortcut format generally used for basic auth is `http://username:password@example.com/path`. You will also want to include the accept header in the request.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I got a response that included the following:

  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

How do I get around that one?

Comment: Sounds like you are not hitting an API endpoint but are instead hitting an endpoint ment for JavaScript to hit.

Comment: This is typically a fine solution - unless your UID or PWD include the ":" or "@" symbols.

Comment: You may have to URL encode the username/password if they contain reserved characters.

Comment: I was trying to use your solution for GET command on HTTPS and it didn't work. e.g https://user:@api.com/v2/shipments
It works in curl. what is wrong? there is no password

Answer (score 4):

in the header section you have to write

Authorization: Basic aG9sY67890vbGNpbQ==

where string after basic is the 64bit encoding value of your username:password.
php example of getting the header values is: 
echo "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("myUser:myPassword");

n.b: I assumed your authentication method as basic. which can be different as well.

Comment: The question specifically asks about how to do it in the Chrome extension Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: Shauna's answer was correct and should be the accepted answer, but this comment from sharif is also useful for those who are curious to know what the Chrome Advanced Rest client has done to encode the user and password for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add authorization header and click pencil button to enter username and passwords

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to get over of this authentication issue is by stealing authentication token using Fiddler.

Steps

1. Fire up fiddler and browser.
2. Navigate browser to open the web application (web site) and do the
   required authentication.
3. Open Fiddler and click on HTTP 200 HTML page request.
   [image: Capturing cookie value using Fiddler]
4. On the right pane, from request headers, copy cookie header
   parameter value.
   [image]
5. Open REST Client and click on "Header form" tab and provide the
   cookie value from the clip board.

Click on SEND button and it shall fetch results.

Answer (score 0):

With latest ARC for GET request with authentication need to add
a raw header named Authorization:authtoken.

Please find the screen shot  [Get request with authentication and query params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzuoe.png)

To add Query param click on drop down arrow on left side of URL box.