# Test complex WebApi method by using Fiddler or what ever extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

Could you tell me how to test below mentioned complex webapi method by using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or what ever extension ? Thanks in advance.

***WebApi method :***

```
 [HttpPost]
 [POST("Sponsors/MyFulfilled/{pledgeId}/{amount}")]
 public string MyFulfilled(int pledgeId, decimal amount, MyConfirmation mp)
        {
           //code here

            return "thanks";
        }
```

**MyConfirmation class :**

```
 public class MyConfirmation
        {
            public string checkoutid { get; set; }
        }
```

***UPDATE:***

I have used like this.But it's not working :(

```
pledgeId=5&amount=88&mp={
"checkoutid":"12"
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason Fiddler is needed? Chrome has a nice extension to test REST. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591770/how-to-test-rest-api-using-chromes-extension-advanced-rest-client

Comment: @lcryder OK, no problem.But I need to construct the above method for post request.So could you tell me how ?

Comment: SoapUI has some pretty good utilities http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html

Comment: The link I provided shows how to do a POST...roughly...pledgeId=5&amount=88&mp=yourJSONMyConfirmationString

Comment: @lcryder It's not working.Please see my UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wth the following configuration in fiddler:

[image: Fiddler Configuration]

[image: Web API Method]

Regards,