# Java Client code to call restful web service

Tags: java, rest, web, service

Can anybody tell me how to write a java client code to call restful *web service* with one parameter say email? I am trying the below code. But I am getting response as **Success**. Once this is success, I need the below `XPHONE` value. How to get this value?

```
XPHONE: 52-33-3669-7000
```

Here is the client code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://bluepages.ibm.com/BpHttpApisv3/wsapi?byInternetAddr=user.email");
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                                .openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                                "application/json");
                        conn.connect();
```

Comment: if the response is in json format you can use the json library http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html otherwise you can parse the string

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missing response body handling.

There is nice article about rest-client code: [article](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/21/jax-rs-restful-client-using-apache-httpclient/).

Comment: Iam trying to implement with this solution. But stucking with HttpClient response which I am unable to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the JavaLite Http client:

[JavaLite Http](http://javalite.io/http)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how API is implemented value can be in response body or even in header, so this info you should know from specification or ask in dev team.

First try to check if everything works fine using CURL or better  "Advanced rest client" ( its extension in Chrome browser) if it works, than just transfer flow to your code. How to use advanced rest client look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591770/how-to-test-rest-api-using-chromes-extension-advanced-rest-client)