# How can I integrate the chrome Advanced Rest Client Application with my c# website?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, advanced-rest-client

I want to post json data by a link to server? I want to integrate chrome Advanced Rest Client Application in my website.How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test REST API using Chrome's extension "Advanced Rest Client"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591770/how-to-test-rest-api-using-chromes-extension-advanced-rest-client)

Comment: No its not that.I don't want to test it.I develop a website and want to pass my json data and link to the Chrome Advanced Rest Client Application. I want to call the Chrome Advanced Rest Client Application in my website.

Comment: I'm the author of the app. But I'm not sure what you want to do here. How it suppose to work? A use case i mean