# How to pass data to Advanced REST client chrome extension

Tags: php, rest, google-chrome

I have a simple php file which just echoes `$_POST['email']`. I want to access it through rest client extension.

New extension looks totally different. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591770/how-to-test-rest-api-using-chromes-extension-advanced-rest-client) uses old extension.

I just added a check `isset($_POST['email'])`. It returns `else` part data.

How do I post data with new extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to setup the request:

1. Since you're accessing email in `$_POST` you'll need to choose the POST method
2. Set the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. Add the data form entries (in your case `email=emailvalue`)

[image]

Then your PHP script will be able to read the value of `$_POST['email']`